# RESTful way of performing validation

Tags: web-services, rest, restful-architecture, api-design

Having worked on SOAP RPC interfaces I'm struggling with how to approach things in a way which fits the RESTful design pattern.

For example. If we have a registration wizard for a new customer which has 3 pages.

The first page for name/DOB
The second page for Address
The third page for other stuff
A final summary page from where the customer completes the registration

The Post of the new customer would be performed from the final summary page so that's obvious, but how would you recommend performing validation of the data entered on each of the pages.

The data on page 1 isn't a customer resource, it's a partial customer resource which requires validation against some server-side business rules (DOB and unique username for example - or something else not easily implemented in JavaScript client validation).

The result of a validation failure may be to offer alternative usernames, so not just a 200/400 status code response.

An RPC design would be a call to a ValidatePage1 method.

But this is thinking of the action 'Validate' on data item and I'm trying to think from a resources and results of an action.

Is it bad design for an API to have REST and RPC type calls, or are there times when this approach is valid when dealing with validation 'actions' which really are actions and not resource posts/gets etc. ValidateDOB, ValidateAge, ValidateAddress etc.

Comment: If it is trivial to visualize as a graph of html documents, then it is suitable for REST.

Answer (score 1):

> For example. If we have a registration wizard for a new customer which has 3 pages.
>
> The first page for name/DOB The second page for Address The third page for other stuff A final summary page from where the customer completes the registration

If you were to do this as HTML, the protocol would probably look something like this -- you would use a bookmark to find a resource, which would deliver to you a representation of the blank form.

You would fill in the form, submit it; the browser would look at the controls on the form to discover the target resource of the form, construct a representation of your form data, and dispatch that representation to the server.  The server would validate your inputs, and either return you (a) a representation of the application state with the errors illustrated, or (b) a representation of the application state with the valid fields locked and a new form to collect the next page of data.  The hyperlinks in this new representation might go to the same place as the previous form, or it might go somewhere else.

At some point you deliver a representation of the form with the data complete and valid, and that takes you to some new application state where you don't have to fill out these forms anymore.

If you do that, you've got REST.

What about the status codes?  Well, each time the form is submitted, the resource is responding with a representation of a new application state, so it's completely appropriate to respond with 200 (OK), even in the cases where the validation failed and we are sending the work back to the user for a do-over.

Notice, that this design doesn't depend at all on:

- What identifiers you use for your resources
- Whether the resources involved map to entities in your domain model
- Whether the resources involved in form validation mutate your domain state